# Unmapped members were found (even when ignoring that property)

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out the issue here. I've used `AutoMapper` throughout this whole project and I've never run into this specific issue. It's complaining about an unmapped property, but I have told it to ignore that property and it's still giving the error.

Here is the model I'm mapping from (**UserDefinedFieldViewModel**):

```
public class UserDefinedFieldViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public UsedFor UsedFor { get; set; }
    public UserDefinedFieldDataType DataType { get; set; }
    public DataTypeDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            switch (DataType)
            {
                case UserDefinedFieldDataType.ShortText:
                    return "Short Text";
                case UserDefinedFieldDataType.LongText:
                    return "Long Text";
                case UserDefinedFieldDataType.Date:
                    return "Date";
                case UserDefinedFieldDataType.Number:
                    return "Number";
                case UserDefinedFieldDataType.Boolean:
                    return "True/False";
                default:
                    return "Unknown";
            }
        }
    }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string HelpText { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the model I'm mapping to (**UserDefinedField**):

```
public class UserDefinedField
{
    public string Id       { get; set; }
    public int OrgId       { get; set; }
    public UsedFor UsedFor { get; set; }
    public UserDefinedFieldDataType DataType { get; set; }
    public string FieldName     { get; set; }
    public string HelpText      { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted       { get; set; }
    public string CreateById    { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate  { get; set; }
    public string LastModById   { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModDate { get; set; }
}
```

The exact error I'm getting is:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
>
> For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>
> UserDefinedFieldViewModel -> UserDefinedField (Destination member list)
>   Web.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.CustomFields.UserDefinedFieldViewModel -> Models.Core.UserDefinedField (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties:
>   OrgId

I'm just not sure what is causing the issue here. I have done this type of mapping throughout the project (including only putting `OrgId` on the actual model) without this error.

I tried ignoring `OrgId` to see if that would work but it doesn't seem to have an effect either. Here is what my mapping currently looks like:

```
x.CreateMap<UserDefinedFieldViewModel, UserDefinedField>().ForMember(dest => dest.OrgId, options => options.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
```

Comment: A repro would be nice.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Don't have time to do that right now. But if I don't get any answers then I'll try and make one. I was hoping there was just something obvious that I was missing lol.

Comment: Try `[IgnoreMap]` attribute on `OrgId` property.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem loading your mapping profile. Check very carefully where you perform the mapping registration [or registrations!]. In my case for this sampe problem, I had overwritten the current registration for another.

Comment: Please post your mapper initialization code to find out the issue with initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error today. At last I figured out that my mapper initialization was incorrect. If you're using .Net Core, you need to create a profile class inheriting from Automapper.Profile and add all mapper configuration in its constructor. Please refer to this post for more details:

https://medium.com/ps-its-huuti/how-to-get-started-with-automapper-and-asp-net-core-2-ecac60ef523f